# on the augmentation ideal

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, define the augmentation map $\varepsilon:\mathbb{Z}G\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\varepsilon(g)=1$ for all $g\in G$. The kernel $I$ of $\varepsilon$ is called the augmentation ideal of $\mathbb{Z}G$.

What I want to prove is this: if $S$ is a set of elements of $G$ such that the elements $s-1\;(s\in S)$ generate $I$ as a left ideal then $S$ generates $G$.

Here what I have done: every element of $I$ is of the form $\sum m_gg(s_g-1)$ where $m_g\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $s_g\in S$. So if $g\in G$ then $g-1\in I$ so $g-1=\sum m_{g_i}g_i(s_i-1)$ from this I want to deduce that $g_1=g, g_0=1$ and $g_i=g_{i+1}s_i^{\pm 1}$.

Comment: Are you aware that the elements $g-1$, $g\neq 1$, are a basis for the augmentation ideal as a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module (i.e., a free abelian groups)?

Comment: @Arturo: yes, I'm aware

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the work you've already done.  While every element of $I$ is of the form $\sum m_{ij} g_i (s_j -1)$, there is no obvious way to simplify this to the form $\sum m_g g(s_g-1)$, even if you allow $s_g=s_{g'}$ for some $g\neq g'$.  In particular, you also don't get such simple expressions for $g-1$.

Comment: @Aaron: I don't know if my approach is right, but it was the only thing that I thought.